# Java - Check for: One or more whitespaces, character, then again one or more whitepsaces

Tags: java, regex, string

im currently doing a little project for school. I have to check if a string is of the following type:

```
"One or more whitespaces" - "On ore more whitespaces"
```

For example: `String s = "  -      "`

I could trim the string and check only for `"-"`, but that doesnt work because `"-"` should be handled differently than `" - "`

I currently tried something like this:

```
if (f.equals(" {1,} -  {1,}"))..
```

but i have no idead what that is exactly doing and it doenst work either.

Can someone help me out?

Shari

Comment: you want to only check or also want to trim the string?

Comment: If you just want to check, checking for " - " is not enough?

Comment: Are you trying to use regex? `equals()` does not work with it.

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/oL9jW3/1) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex: `"^\\s+-\\s$+"`

You can use `String.matches()`, because `.equals` doesn't do regexes.

"Untainted" version:
`^\s+-\s+$`

## Explanation

`^` and `$` anchor to the ends of the string.

`\s+` matches one or more whitespace(s).

Comment: thank you.
i did it like this: string.matches(" +- +");

Answer (score 0):

You need to use groups. Use `(` and `)` to establish groups.
To answer your question I think this would work:

```
^(\s+) - (\s+)$
(\s+|\s*) - (\s+|\s*)
```

the `*` means 0 or more
the `+` means 1 or more, so if you're matching 1 or more, you should have no white spaces around your pattern ie:  `-`

A very good 'toy' is [this](http://regexr.com/).
Just hovering over the characters shows you details, you have a cheat-sheet and many more!

Answer (score 0):

```
reg = "\s+-\s+"
```

This will probably do it.